# Grabbing JSON data from the source code for a userscript

Tags: javascript, json, tampermonkey

I am writing a userscript for Tampermonkey (in Javascript), but I'm still a Javascript beginner and I can't figure out one thing on my own.

I want my script to grab some data from JSON which is embedded in the website's source code, and show me that data right on the page (I hope I'm explaining that correctly). The issue I'm having is that I don't know how to write a function that would grab that JSON data for me.

If I go to the page source, here's the structure of the code I'm seeing:

```
<script>// <![CDATA[
window["obvInit"]({"XXX":{
"YYY":"12345",
"ZZZ":"1234566",
"BBB":"134565",
...
})
// ]]></script>
```

Basically I would need to create a function which goes to the website's source code and gets the value for YYY (which would be "12345"). How can I do that?

Comment: If that structure is always the same, just fetch the page (with ajax) as text and slice out that part of the string that represents the page source.

Comment: Here's a pretty crude way to do it: https://jsfiddle.net/73ns502r/

Comment: Thanks guys, this is super helpful!